# how to use mongodb indexing in nodejs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to build a search module using mongodb indexing but not sure how to use it on the collection created using mongoose

i.e,
db.books.createIndex({"Title":"text"}) this works fine in mongo shell
where books is a collection which is inside database called  bookish

but how to use it in nodejs application where i have few apis calls defined

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(router);
};

/*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  Defining Model  Starts++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
Books =  mongoose.model('Books');

/*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  Defining Model  Stops++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/





/*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   Router  Starts++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
router.route('/api/book/')
  .get(function(req,res){
    Books.find({},function(err,books){
      console.log( req.params.id);
      res.send(books);
    })
  });

router.route('/api/delete/book/:id')
  .post(function(req,res){
    console.log("delete id"+req.params.id)
    Books.findOne({bookId: req.params.id}, function(err,updateRemoveBook) {
      updateRemoveBook.isDeleteBook= 0;
      updateRemoveBook.save();
      res.send(updateRemoveBook);
    });
  });

router.route('/cerateIndex')
Books.createIndex({"subject":"text","content":"text"})
```

in this file how to create index on this book ie here books is a refrence of model but create Index should be called on the collection right

i am not able to do like

```
db.Books.createIndex({"subject":"text","content":"text"})
```

i am referring this article to perform indexing
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835

not sure how to use it with nodejs application please provide suggestion to how to go about it  point some sample which can demonstrate the same

Answer (score 0):

You can create the text indexes using the model schema's **[`index()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index)** method:

```
bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({"subject": String, "content": String},{"collection": "books"});    
bookSchema.index({ "subject": "text", "content": "text" });
Books =  mongoose.model('Books', bookSchema);
```